# is there a way in marionetteJS application object to aggregate vent events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

is there a way in marionette to aggregate events?

i mean it would be much easier to change this:

```
           MyApp.vent.on("taskMoved", function(moveData){
              // taskId, fromBucketId, toBucketId, order, $li
              moveTask(moveData.taskId,moveData.fromBucketId, moveData.toBucketId, moveData.order, moveData.li);
            });

            MyApp.vent.on("taskMovedLast", function(moveData){
              // taskId, fromBucketId, toBucketId, order, $li
              moveTaskLast(moveData.taskId, moveData.fromBucketId, 99);
            });

            MyApp.vent.on("taskMovedFirst", function(moveData){
              // taskId, fromBucketId, toBucketId, order, $li
              moveTaskFirst(moveData.taskId, moveData.fromBucketId, 99);
            });
```

into this:

```
 {
"taskMoved":"moveTask",
"taskMovedLast":"taskMovedLast",
"taskMovedFirst":"taskMovedFirst"
}
```

similar to the BackboneView event object.

can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method that did that but as far as I can tell from my work with Marionette, you cannot.

However, you could do something like:

```
bind_events: function(events_hash){
    var that = this;
    _.each(events_hash, function(func, evt){
        MyApp.vent.on(evt, that[func]);
    }
};
```

Pass in that hash and it will turn them all on for you.

Comment: Obviously you'd want to make that a part of the object that contains the methods for which you're binding those events... :)

Comment: sure thing - i want to keep chrome's console happy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind to all vent events try :

```
vent.on('all',this.trigger.bind(this))
```

this is a good idea, if you want to use vent as a "proxy/mediator"